# Interrupts using member function

Tags: embedded, interrupts, firmware, c++, development

- I am trying to use a member function in an interrupt. The function uses member variables so I created a global instance of that class to use it in a static function.
  The problem is that I created a child class that should have the same interrupt. The interrupt is enabled in the constructor of the parent class, so it will be also enabled in the child class but with the wrong instance.
- To use the interrupt functions in both classes, I put them in a separate header file "Utilities.h" so that I can included it in both source files. But doing `void called_from_interrupt () { Instance_1.do_something(); }` requires including the class header, which will create multiple definitions errors.

I'll put a short example of what I am trying to do, the original code is really long.

parent_class.h :

```
#ifndef PARENT_CLASS_H
#define PARENT_CLASS_H

class parent_class {

public :

    parent_class();
    ~parent_class();
    void do_something();
};

extern parent_class instance_1;

#endif
```

parent_class.cpp :

```
#ifndef PARENT_CLASS_CPP
#define PARENT_CLASS_CPP

#define LIBCALL_ENABLEINTERRUPT
#define EI_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTED_PIN
#include "EnableInterrupt.h"

#include utilities.h

parent_class instance_1;

parent_class::parent_class() {

    enableInterrupt(PIN_1, called_from_interrupt, FALLING);
}

parent_class::~parent_class() {}

parent_class::do_something() {

    //manipulate some member variables
}

#endif
```

child_class.h :

```
#ifndef CHILD_CLASS_H
#define CHILD_CLASS_H

class child_class {

public :

    child_class();
    ~child_class();
};

extern child_class instance_2;

#endif
```

child_class.cpp :

```
#ifndef CHILD_CLASS_CPP
#define CHILD_CLASS_CPP

#include utilities.h

child_class instance_2;

child_class::child_class() {}

child_class::~child_class() {}


#endif
```

utilities.h :

```
#ifndef UTILITIES_H
#define UTILITIES_H

#include "parent_class.h"

#define PIN_1  10

static void called_from_interrupt() {
    instance_1.do_something();
}

#endif
```

Do you have please an elegant solution for that ?

Comment: This is a bit broad and missing in detail to be specifically answerable, but it sounds like you may be losing sight of the general need to keep what happens in an ISR extremely minimal.  Be very wary of access to things like class variables, especially if they are multi-byte.

Comment: There are two quite distinct questions in your question that don't rely on each other. To maximise your chances of getting quality answers, create two questions. Also, the answer is unrelated to Arduino, so try a programming site like StackOverflow. Finally, check your technical terms to be very clear - I think by "class member function", "subclass", "base class", and "extern instance" you mean "member function", "child class", "parent class" and "global instance" respectively. One word can make a big difference!

Comment: @ChrisStratton I added some examples.
Unfortunately it is not my code and changing the interrupt function requires changing how the code is working. I am trying to find an elegant solution so I don't have to touch all the functions. It is  the best solution though.

Comment: @HeathRaftery Thank you for your comment ! I modified the description. I think that the two questions are related so I kept them together.

Comment: You're probably going to have to make deeper changes than you like, then.  Or maybe you can do the actual timing-required task in the interrupt, and then set a flag and call the member function from the foreground context later.  You can read up on the singleton design pattern and how to implement it, but that just means your code will compile, it doesn't mean that the memory access your member function may utilize is safe to actually execute in an ISR.  Keeping the ISR separate and its interaction with any other state explicit would help you keep those interactions safe.

Comment: Instead of making the ISR a member function, you should make the program state that the ISR must interact with global volatile variables, which you access only in an atomic fashion (ie with interrupts disabled).  If you want to think of it in an OOP sort of way, consider the state the ISR is able to modify to be something you may only access outside the ISR via a getter, and make that getter atomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the static member of the base class should work.
You just have to make sure the `Instance` **pointer** is correct.
This can be done with the singleton pattern.

Be aware of potential reentrancy risk with this approach though.

---

Example (disclaimer: I have not dealt with this exact problem before):
https://godbolt.org/z/a6qj3c

```
class Base {
protected:
    static Base *instance;
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base(){}
public:
    static Base* getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
    static void setInstance(Base* p){
        instance = p;
    }
    virtual void run();
};

Base* Base::instance;

class Child : public Base {
public:
    Child(){
        Base::setInstance(this);
    }
    ~Child() override {
        Base::setInstance(nullptr);
    }
    void run() override;
};

void Base::run(){
    cout << "the base thing" << endl;
}

void Child::run() {
    cout << "the child thing" << endl;
}

extern "C" void isr(){
    if(Base::getInstance() != nullptr)
        Base::getInstance()->run();
}

int main()
{
    Child b;
    isr();
    return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
the child thing
```

Now, **big red flag**, you can call `Child::run()` from **two contexts**. Your main thread *and* your interrupt routine. This means that Child::run() can be called while executing Child::run(), this a reentrancy problem.

Comment: Very good suggestion, but probably hard to use for someone of the OP's skill level. Some example code might make a big difference.

Comment: If one is going to do this, indeed a singleton is probably necessary.  But realistically, one should *not* do this - especially if such concepts are unfamiliar.

Comment: @Jeroen3 The problem is that a static member function should not use non static member variables. Can you please give me an example of how to use a singleton pattern ?

Comment: The singleton pattern is something you can research yourself (requests for examples are explicitly prohibited), but you also need to worry about the *consistency* of memory accessed in both an ISR and the main thread.  The very kinds of things you want this to be a member function in order to accomplish, are the kinds of things that will get you into trouble in an ISR.

Comment: @FF504 [The Singleton Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton)

Comment: @HeathRaftery Added code example. May not be the best though... Perhaps is missing some tactical consts...

Comment: Reentrancy is unlikely to be a problem, because the member function that would implement an ISR wouldn't be useful for anything else.  Rather, the major problem is data *consistency* - much as when dealing with multi-threaded code.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Thank you for the example. As chris said, there will not be any reentrancy in my case because I don't use that function anywhere else.

Comment: @Jeroen3 How can I use the basic class instance ? I tried `Base b` in main but the pointer *instance was null.

Comment: @FF504 `setInstance(this)` in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are hell-bent on using C++ for some reason, then the correct solution is not to create one big "goo" class but to use OO design. Place the ISR as a static function - optionally it can be static member - inside a dedicated singleton "interrupt class", which does nothing but handling the interrupt for that specific hardware peripheral. Re-entrancy protection and interrupt enable/disabled is also handled by that class.

Then include the interrupt class as a private one inside the general hardware peripheral driver code.

This way you can also potentially expose the "interrupt class" to the vector table, so that the ISR name is known to it - without exposing any other internals of the hardware peripheral class. You will find out that the ISR needs to be exposed to the vector table regardless - after which you realize it would have been easier just to make the ISR a plain file scope function like you would have done in C.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What do you mean by "expose to the vector table" ?

Comment: @FF504 Any sound microcontroller design has the interrupt vector table as a separate .c file (though in some cases it's crappily merged into the CRT or handled entirely by the linker). That .c file will need to know the name of your ISR function or it can't register it.